# Converting a string of digits into their hex equivalents

Tags: java

I tried this

```
String dataC =  Integer.toHexString(dataB);
```

But of course that wouldn't work with a string...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`toHexString` requires integer as argument, so how about changing string of digits to integer first?

```
String dataC =  Integer.toHexString(Integer.parseInt(dataB));
```

(more readable code)

```
int dataBInteger = Integer.parseInt(dataB);
String dataC =  Integer.toHexString(dataBInteger);
```

---

If value from string is in range of `long` (-9223372036854775808; 9223372036854775807) you can use

```
String dataC =  Long.toHexString(Long.parseLong(dataB));
```

---

If you don't want to assume any limit of number of digits you can use [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)

```
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(dataB);
String dataC = bi.toString(16);
```

Comment: it's a long string of digits

Comment: @user3293056 Can I know how long? Does it have predefined limit?

Comment: a few thousand i guess. potentially more later.

Comment: RE your update, can you write it in terms of String dataC instead of printing it please ?

Comment: thanks. but

CONVERTLETTERS.java:47: error: cannot find symbol
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(dataB);
^
  symbol:   class BigInteger
  location: class CONVERTLETTERS
CONVERTLETTERS.java:47: error: cannot find symbol
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(dataB);
                    ^
  symbol:   class BigInteger
  location: class CONVERTLETTERS
2 errors

Comment: You need to add `import` to `java.math.BigInteger` class. Place `import java.math.BigInteger;` at start of your code (below package declaration if you have one).

Answer (score 0):

You should first convert dataB string to int:

```
int number = Integer.parseInt(dataB);
String dataC =  "0x" + Integer.toHexString(number);
```

Comment: i tried this, but when i printed the result i didn't get hex just normal integers  ?

Answer (score 0):

As it's a long string, try

```
String hex = new BigInteger(dec).toString(16);
```